# Deleting entries in excel macro when entries are different

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to create a program that will Search through an excel file and delete duplicate entries.

I have made this code that does this. However, I also need it to delete the entry before the duplicate and after the duplicate. I've looked everywhere and can not find any examples, please help!

These are my example entries

```
The1
Car
Car
The2
```

I'd need it to delete The1 and both Car entries leaving the The2. 
Here is my code so far

```
Sub rar()
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'DEFINES WHICH SHEET TO USE'
      For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
          Rows(i+1).Delete
          Rows(i).Delete
          Rows(i-1).delete  
        End If
     Next i
  End With   
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to me that this code does the job that you want. Except the fact that you need to change the index of rows to `i-2`, `i-1`, and `i` instead of what they are right now and delete those rows.

Comment: Work with Offset Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chris Neilsen pointed out below - using `With` was a great idea, but you need to put a `.` before your cell and range references to ensure they refer to the worksheet you specified in your `With` token

Try this:

```
Sub rar()
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'DEFINES WHICH SHEET TO USE'
      For i = 3 to .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Rows(i - 2 & ":" & i)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Rows(i - 2 & ":" & i))
            End If 
        End If
     Next i
  End With 
  rng.Delete  
End Sub
```

*Note: untested - but the idea is to create build up your range as you loop through and then delete at the end. This way you don't have to worry about looping backwards.*

Comment: I think you missed the absence of `.`'s to reference the `With` block variable